# Database Table Design: Expanding a data table while maintaining backwards compatibility

Tags: database, oracle, jsp, database-design, relational-database

The project I'm working on tracks data on a year by year basis. The user will log into the system and specify the year it wants to access the data of. For example, the user could specify the year 2004, and the .jsp pages will display 2004 data.

My problem is that from 2013 onward, the data for one .jsp page will be different, and the current database table schema needs to be modified, but backwards compatibility for the 2012 and before years needs to be maintained.

Currently (2012 and before), the relevant database table displays two columns, "continuing students" & "new starts" that is displayed by a single .jsp. For 2013 and onward, 4 columns need to be displayed. The original two columns are being split into two subcategories each, undergrad and graduate. So I can't simply add those new columns to the existing table because that would violate third normal form.

What do you think the best way to manage this situation? How do I display the new data while still maintaining backwards compatibility to display the data for older years?

Comment: Curious, when you say backwards compatibility needs to be maintained, do you mean for reads and writes or just reads?

Comment: just reads. the new data for 2013 onward will be how the system adds any new data

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

1. Introduce the fields and allow for nulls for older data.  I think you rejected this idea.
2. Create new table structures to store the new data going forward.  It's an least an option if you don't want (1).  You could easily create a view that queries from both tables and presents a unified set of data.  You could also handle this in the UI and call two separate stored procedures depending on the year queried.
3. Create a new table with the new attributes and then optionally join back to your original table.  This keeps the old table the same and the new table is just an extension of the old data.  You would write a stored procedure potentially to take in the year and then return the appropriate data.

One of the things to really consider is that the old data is now inactive.  If you aren't writing to it anymore, it's just historical data that can be "archived" mentally.  In that case I think it's ok to freeze the schema and the data and let it live by itself.

Also consider if your customers are likely to change the schema yet again.  If so, then maybe (1) is the best.

Comment: +1. But there's really no way to insulate jsp from the creation of new columns. (That fits at least one definition of *backward compatibility*.) The jsp programmers either write code that makes no assumptions about the number of columns, or they don't. I'd favor option 2, and replacing the existing table by renaming it and creating a view that unions all rows, past and future, with the current two-column format.

Comment: @ryan1234 Thanks for the input. I've never worked with stored procedures before, so I do not fully understand them yet.

Comment: @ryan1234 Probably because of my lack of expertise on stored procedures, I'm thinking about going with a second table for 2013 onward, and just modifying the .jsp to use different tables for <= 2012 and >= 2013, and display the data appropriately.

Let me know if that's a bad thought process. Thanks!